# Error in writeLines function R : Permission denied

Tags: r, permissions, chmod

I am trying to run the following code Error in R

```
dat <- yaml::yaml.load_file('/home/aaaa/bbbbb/ccc/dddd.yml')
fileConn <- file(configFile)
writeLines(yaml::as.yaml(dat), fileConn) :
```

I am getting the error

```
Error in writeLines(yaml::as.yaml(dat), fileConn) :
cannot open file '/home/aaaa/bbbbb/ccc/dddd.yml': Permission denied
```

Comment: I also tried getting permission using chmod 777 /home/aaaa/bbbbb/ccc/dddd.yml, but that didnt solve the error

Comment: What OS are you on? Does the folder `/home/aaaa/bbbbb/ccc/` already exist? Is `/home/aaaa/` your own home folder? Where is the value of `configFile` defined? Can you view the contents of the `dat` to confirm it was able to read from that file?

Comment: The folder /home/aaaa/bbbbb/ccc/ exists.   The /home/aaaa/bbbbb folder is actually /home/dsp/deploy( the deploy subfolder is created during local build runtime).  The configFile is defined above in the code by configFile <- file.path("/home/aaaa/bbbbb/ccc/", "config", "user.config.yml").   I will not be able to read it as this code is a part of an internal function